# Get column aliases from sql query

Tags: postgresql

From a query like that:

```
select
        aaa.rank as my_rank,
        aa.*,
        aa.article_category
from
        articles.article_article_authors as aaa
        left join article_article as aa on aa.id = aaa.article_id
;
```

I would like to get column aliases - in this particular case alias `my_rank` for column `aaa.rank`. Unfortunately, using `EXPLAIN` with whatever option wouldn't give me the information I need:

```
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
      "Join Type": "Left",
      "Startup Cost": 0.00,
      "Total Cost": 2.66,
      "Plan Rows": 1,
      "Plan Width": 70,
      "Output": ["aaa.article_id", "aaa.user_id", "aaa.rank", "aa.id", "aa.creation_time", "aa.pub_start", "aa.pub_end", "aa.is_visible", "aa.rank", "aa.answer_to_article_id", "aa.title", "aa.hits", "aa.meta_keywords", "aa.content", "aa.archived", "aa.article_category", "aa.article_category"],
      "Join Filter": "(aa.id = aaa.article_id)",
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Relation Name": "article_article_authors",
          "Schema": "public",
          "Alias": "aaa",
          "Startup Cost": 0.00,
          "Total Cost": 1.01,
          "Plan Rows": 1,
          "Plan Width": 12,
          "Output": ["aaa.id", "aaa.article_id", "aaa.user_id", "aaa.rank"]
        },
        {
          "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
          "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
          "Relation Name": "article_article",
          "Schema": "public",
          "Alias": "aa",
          "Startup Cost": 0.00,
          "Total Cost": 1.29,
          "Plan Rows": 29,
          "Plan Width": 58,
          "Output": ["aa.id", "aa.creation_time", "aa.pub_start", "aa.pub_end", "aa.is_visible", "aa.rank", "aa.answer_to_article_id", "aa.title", "aa.hits", "aa.meta_keywords", "aa.content", "aa.archived", "aa.article_category"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Is there a way to get column aliases using `explain`, or should I follow some other path? Of course I could parse the query string and then get my column aliases, but I'd rather like to postgres do this for me.

Comment: Why are you needing to do this?  What post-processing of the column names are you trying to do?  It may be that you have a simpler use case that doesn't require this level of analysis.

Comment: [this may interest you](http://regex101.com/r/lC3oF1)..

Comment: Cool, will do -- give me some time for an explanation..just wanted to make sure this helps in your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a regular expression to match all columns/aliases of a SQL string.  I think I covered the majority of scenarios, but I may have missed some.

```
(?:              # Start non-capturing group
  select         # Match "select" literally
 |               # OR
  \G             # Match the end of the previous match (our last column)
)                # End non-capturing group
\s+              # Catch extra whitespace
\K               # Remove everything to the left from the match
(?:              # Start non-capturing group
  (?:            # Start non-capturing group
    .*?          # Lazily match column (this can be modified to your needs)
    \s+as\s+     # Match " as " literally
    ([^,]+)      # Capture the alias (anything but a comma)
    ,?           # Optional comma
  )              # End non-capturing group
 |               # OR
  ([^,]+)        # Capture the column (anything but a comma)
  ,?             # Optional comma
)                # End non-capturing group
(?=              # Start lookahead
  .*?            # Lazily match characters (whitespace)
  \bfrom\b       # Up to "from" literally (with word delimiters)
)                # End lookahead
```

This will capture aliases in the first group and columns in the second group, the whole string will be matched.  It will likely have problems if you start having crazy column aliases, but seems to match anything basic to intermediate.  Note I used the modifiers `gsi` for global, dot-matches-newline, and case-insenstive.

[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/kK4nT4)